# Complex UML use case diagram

Tags: uml, use-case

I made this use case diagram:

[image]

My project is a village profile website. It is made for collecting the questions from the researcher who wants answers directly from the locals, for any reasons: covid, communication etc.

As I am not experienced with use-cases,I want to make sure that I am going in the right way. Is this diagram correct?

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. I have slightly reworded the title (to make it more useful for people with similar issues) and the question (to make it more specific, and prevent subjective answers). I hope it’s ok for you.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: if your UC diagrams resemble spider webs then your design is likely broken.

Answer (score 1):

A use-case diagram is about the big picture and the goals (use-case bubble) that a system (the rectangle) helps its actors to achieve.

According to your diagram, there would be 5 independent systems, each with some use-cases that address different needs. Is this really what you wanted to model?

When zooming into the different systems, it appears that these are not independent systems but function groups (i.e. groups of features that offer some functionality).  It appears moreover that the use-cases do not correspond to user-goals, but to detailed functions related to the function group. So you seem to do some kind of functional decomposition.

Functional decomposition is fine. But not with use-cases! It always leads to very detailed diagrams that loose the big picture and end to be unrelated to the user’s interest.

Use-cases are not either meant for user-interface design (in case you wanted each rectangle correspond to some windows/pages),  or for decomposing the internal structure of the system (in case you wanted each component to correspond to some microservice or whatever).  Use-case should focus only on user goals that add value to the user (typically not a login, which is only a constraint for what the user really want to do).

Good news: there remains good potential to significantly simplify this diagram ;-)